# Close() Method Not closing Window when called WPF C#

Tags: c#, wpf

I'm trying to close a window in WPF, however when I call `Close();` it isn't doing anything.

This is the method in my main class `MainWindow` where I call `Close();`

```
public void UserVerified(bool verified)    {
    if (verified == true)        {
        Console.WriteLine("closing...");
        Close();
    }
}
```

I have a method in another class, which I pass this method too:

```
if (answer.detail == null)    {
  verify = true;                     
}
else    {
  verify = false;
}
check.UserVerified(verify);
```

I also have a function when `Close();` is used not to quit the application, rather push it to the System Tray, which is:

```
protected override void OnClosing(CancelEventArgs e)
{
    e.Cancel = true;
    Hide();
    base.OnClosing(e);
}
```

`Close();` works in other methods in the MainWindow class however it seems when I run a MainWindow method in another class' method it doesn't work.

It should be noted that it is entering the `if (verified == true) {...}` statement as the console line is displayed.

Answer (score 1):

Try calling `Application.Current.Shutdown()` instead of `Close()`.

Also, I believe it is a better practice to use:

```
if (verified)
```

instead of:

```
if (verified == true)
```

Same for using:

```
verify = answer.detail == null;
```

instead of:

```
if (answer.detail == null)    {
  verify = true;                     
}
else    {
  verify = false;
}
```

Comment: Actually a lot of style frameworks force the `== true` for clarity reasons. But you're 100% correct in the `Application.Current.Shutdown()` because that is the best way to confirm all threads from the process have been killed. So it's a up vote from me :)